# CatRoot using 100% of my disk for several minutes at a time

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-11

Sometimes, my SSD's disk usage spikes to 100% because of CatRoot oem* files. This makes my computer extremely slow, and it stays this way for several minutes until it magically resolves itself (temporarily).

The most consistent trigger I've found so far is that every time after I restart my PC and attempt to join a Discord voice call, my disk usage spikes to 100%, and Discord gets stuck on "RTC Connecting" until the problem resolves. Rarely, though, this problem will happen even if I'm not in a voice call, so that's not the only cause.

For reference, this is what I see:
[image: CatRoot high disk usage]

As seen in the screenshot, it seems that some dozens of CatRoot oem* files are collectively performing millions of disk reads per second whenever this happens. No clue what they're reading, but it's super intensive. After the problem resolves, the disk usage goes back to its usual 0-2% during idle time.

Here's what I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Discord
- Deleting or renaming the folders at `Windows\System32\catroot2` and `Windows\SoftwareDistribution`
- `sfc /scannow` (found nothing)
- Scanning for malware with Malwarebytes and Windows Defender's offline scan (found nothing)

I read online that I'm not supposed to mess with the `System32\CatRoot` folder or else my PC won't boot, so I'm completely lost now.

Comment: This a recent problem?

Comment: 2MB/sec Disk I/O resulting in 100% Disk Active at 8.1KB/s write speed .... that doesn't sound good

Comment: Yes, this has been happening for around a week or so.

Comment: I'd download `SSD S.M.A.R.T. TOOL` from the SSD manufacturers website *`support.teamgroupinc.com/en/support/download.php`* and check the drive

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the suggestion, what am I looking for? I downloaded the tool and ran it, and it says my SSD's Health Status is "Good (99%)", so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: OK - to me it looked like your SSD may have been on its way to god, based on the image you posted - but, guess it's not that

Comment: Ah, I did get the SSD less than half a year ago so it would suck if it already broke.